# How aright get count rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Good day.**

**Structure tables [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fed6a)**

**Original structure tables with foreignt keys(cannt add in sqlfiddle) [here](http://pastebin.com/PqVxqJx8)**

**Code:**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as count 
FROM Price p 
    left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service 
              AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm 
    left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city 
    left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
    left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service 
              AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm 
WHERE 
    p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' 
    AND p.blocked='0' AND f.blocked='0' 
    AND f.dogovor='1' AND d.end_date >= '20131003 17:10:30' 
    AND (p.name LIKE 'test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS) 
GROUP BY 
    p.id_price, 
    p.id_service, 
    p.name, 
    p.name_original, 
    p.id_producer_country, 
    p.id_firm, 
    f.name, 
    f.address, 
    f.phone, 
    city.name, 
    pc.name
```

**I would like get count rows, but in result i get next:**

[image: 1]

**if i use column name in `count`, ex. code:**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(p.id_price) as count
```

**i get the same result...**

***Anyone know how get on count all rows?***

***P.S.: in result me need get count unique rows***:

```
p.name, 
p.name_original, 
p.id_producer_country, 
p.id_firm, 
f.name, 
f.address, 
f.phone, 
city.name, 
pc.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as count 
FROM Price p 
left join Firm f on f.id_service = p.id_service 
            AND f.id_city = p.id_city AND f.id_firm = p.id_firm 
left join City city on city.id_city = p.id_city 
left join Producer_country pc on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
left join Dogovor d on d.id_service=p.id_service 
              AND d.id_city=p.id_city AND d.id_firm=p.id_firm 
WHERE 
    p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' 
    AND p.blocked='0' AND f.blocked='0' 
    AND f.dogovor='1' AND d.end_date >= '20131003 17:10:30' 
    AND (p.name LIKE 'test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS);
```

Use the `GROUP BY`, if you want each row in the result set as a group and represents one or more rows with the same values in one or more columns that you specify in the `GROUP BY`. But in your case, you want the count of all the rows, so there is no need for it.

Comment: but how i get unique rows? if i remove Group by i get all rows, but me need only unique...

Comment: @TeopLome - Do you mean the count of distinct rows? Use `COUNT(DISTINCT columnname)` this will count only unique values, but will give you one total value.

Comment: i use `COUNT(
 DISTINCT 
 p.id_price, 
 p.id_service, 
 p.name, 
 p.name_original, 
 p.id_producer_country, 
 p.id_firm, 
 f.name, 
 f.address, 
 f.phone, 
 city.name, 
 pc.name
 
 ) as count ` but i get error `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

How i can get unique rows?

Comment: @TeopLome - Use only one column in the `COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_service)`, if you want other counts of other columns put each one in a separate count: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_service), COUNT(DISTINCT p.name), ...`

Comment: no-no you are not understand -  i want get **one count all unique rows** `p.id_price, p.id_service, p.name, p.name_original, p.id_producer_country, p.id_firm, f.name, f.address, f.phone, city.name, pc.name` it not count each column..

Comment: @TeopLome Can you please give me some sample data from the tables and the desired output that you are looking for?

Comment: @TeopLome - For the sqlfiddle demo you give in your question, there is no table `price`. And please give the desired output for the sample data in the demo.

Comment: sorry data very big for fiddle, i add table price and refresh link to fidle. **SqlFiddle [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fed6a)** **Pastebin [LINK](http://pastebin.com/PqVxqJx8)**

Comment: @TeopLome - Try `SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.name), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.name_original), 
COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_producer_country), 
COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_firm), 
COUNT(DISTINCT f.name), 
COUNT(DISTINCT f.address), 
COUNT(DISTINCT f.phone), 
COUNT(DISTINCT city.name), 
COUNT(DISTINCT pc.name) ...`, see it [**in this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fed6a/3)

Comment: if i try your code i get unique rows or i get count each unique value in each column ?

Comment: @TeopLome It should give you the total count (one value) of the unique values for each column, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `COUNT(*)` use the desired unique field name from any of your joined table to get the singular count

Comment: **if i use column name in `count`, ex. code:**

    SELECT 
     COUNT(p.id_price) as count 
**i get the same result...**

Comment: try counting that column without the group by clause. Grouping by a column with distinct values gives you distinct rows of your result.